# revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

Tags: ganache-cli

I try to send from ERC-20 to other ERC-20 via interledger in ganache , but get this error:

```
     {
 <     "id": 3451,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "error": {
 <       "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance",
 <       "code": -32000,
 <       "data": {
 <         "stack": "c: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance\n    at Function.c.fromResults (/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js:2:257479)\n    at e.exports (/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js:53:1406305)",
 <         "name": "c"
 <       }
 <     }
 <   }
```

(but Im shure that balances are full I cheked them by truffle)

Comment: This is a 100% case when your balance is too low. This might be the problem with: you use a different account to make a transfer and different account to check balance, you send your transaction to the wrong ERC20 contract, or you may have some mix up with your providers. You may use a different provider when you check balance and different when you make a transfer. This may happen some times. We would have to see your code to help you here. So if you can at least paste code you use to make a transfer and check balance then it would be helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question here, and there is one obvious way to solve the problem, exactly as implied in the error-message.

Comment: Can you show the source code that causes the error? It is probably as Rob says the code doesn't match your intentions.

Comment: You right, I just use wrong address (credentials) of sender. Thanks for answers!

P.S. Did I need to close the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you right, I just use wrong address (credentials) of sender (that have empty balance). 
Thanks for answers!